# A subset of an ordered set $(X,<)$ is called *dense* in X. So, Is A dense in A? Is A dense in $\mathbb{Q^{\geq 0}}$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A subset *A* of an ordered set $(X,<)$ is called **dense** in X, if for all $x<y$ in $X$, there is an $a\in$ *A* such that $x<a<y$. Let $A=${$q^2 : q\in\mathbb{Q}$}. Order *A* naturally the induced order of $\mathbb{Q}$). Is *A* dense in *A*?  Is *A* dense in $\mathbb{Q^{\geq 0}}$, Is *A* dense in $\mathbb{R^{\geq 0}}$ ?

Comment: I think YES! YES! YES!. Yet, I couldn't prove.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: All three questions are similar. For the third, suppose that $x,y\in\Bbb R^{\ge 0}$, and $x<y$. Then $\sqrt{x}<\sqrt{y}$. I assume that you know that $\Bbb Q$ is dense in $\Bbb R$, so you know that there is a rational number $q$ such that $\sqrt{x}<q<\sqrt{y}$. What can you say about $q^2$?